# node.js how to find a document inside Inner Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please teach me how to find a document inside Inner Mongodb. I'd like to bring you some coordinates inside the market. What should I do?

```
/**
 * 데이터베이스 스키마를 정의하는 모듈
 *
 * @date 2016-11-10
 * @author Mike
 */

//var crypto = require('crypto');

var Schema = {};

Schema.createSchema = function(mongoose) {

    // 스키마 정의
    var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        itemName : {type: String, index: 'hashed', 'default':''}
        ,market : {
             marketName: {type: String, index: 'hashed', 'default':''}
           , marketId: {type: String, required: true, 'default':''} //마켓 고유번호
           , geometry: {
                type: {type:String, default:'Point'},
                coordinates: [{type:'Number'}]
                }
            , tel: {type: String, required: true, 'default':''}
            , address: { data: Buffer, contentType: String,default:''  }
        }

        ,price : { type: 'Number',default:''}
        ,disPrice: {type: 'Number',default:''}
        ,count: {type: 'Number',default:''}

        ,expireTime : {type: Date, index: {unique: false} }

    });

    console.log('ItemSchema 정의함.');


     ItemSchema.index({geometry:'2dsphere'});


    ItemSchema.static('findNear',function(longitude,latitude,maxDistance,callback){
       console.log('findNear 호출됨')

        this.find().where('geometry').near({

            center:{

                type:'Point',
                coordinates:[parseFloat(longitude),parseFloat(latitude)]

        },

            maxDistance:maxDistance
        }).exec(callback);

    });      



    return ItemSchema;
};

// module.exports에 UserSchema 객체 직접 할당
module.exports = Schema;
```

this is router

var findNearItem = function(req, res) {
    console.log(' findNearData.');

```
var paramLongitude = req.body.longitude || req.query.longitude;
var paramLatitude = req.body.latitude || req.query.latitude;
var maxDistance = 10000;

var database = req.app.get('database');

database.ItemModel.findNear(paramLongitude, paramLatitude, maxDistance, function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('결과 -> ' + JSON.stringify(results));

    var context = {
        results:results
    };

    var output = JSON.stringify(context);
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
    res.write(output);
    res.end();
});
```

};

this is config

{file:'./item',path:'/process/findNearItem',method:'findNearItem',type:'post'}

Comment: You want to return just the sub document coordinates ? if it yes, you want to return it for every item name ? please provide more info

Comment: I wish I could return only the coordinates.

Comment: I want to get all the information within Max Distance of the coordinates I send.

Answer (score 0):

The find query return the whole record document, even if the query condition checking on an attribute in the sub document of the record like coordinates but in your case you want to return just the coordinates sub document.

I suggest using aggregate.

```
this.aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id:"$market.geometry.coordinates"
          }
    }])
```

If you want to have the max value of coordinates in a maxDistance field

```
db.getCollection('market').aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id:"$market.geometry.coordinates"
          }},{
          $project: { maxDistance: { $max: "$_id" }} //_id here is refering to "market.geometry.coordinates"
      }])
```

Pipeline builder technique within schema static method:

```
ItemSchema.static('findNear',function(longitude,latitude,maxDistance,callback){
   console.log('findNear 호출됨');

return this.aggregate().group({
            _id:"$market.geometry.coordinates"
          }).project({
            maxDistance: { $max: "$_id" }
          }).exec(callback);

});
```

Comment: ItemSchema.static ( 'findNear', function (longitude, latitude, maxDistance, callback) {console.log ( 'findNear 호출 됨') this.aggregate ([{$ group : {_id : "$ market.geometry.coordinates"} , maxDistance : maxDistance}]). exec (콜백);}); return ItemSchema; }; I wrote this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: you don't have an attribute maxDistance, you want to calculate the max value of the coordinates ?

Comment: im so sorry I'm a novice developer. I don't know what to do. If you use the above code ,Node goes off

Answer (score 0):

sorry I can't use aggregate, I solved the problem by modifying the ItemSchema .

```
var ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    itemName : {type: String, index: 'hashed', 'default':''}
       , marketName: {type: String, index: 'hashed', 'default':''}
       , marketId: {type: String, required: true, 'default':''} //마켓 고유번호
       , geometry: {
            type: {type:String, default:'Point'},
            coordinates: [{type:'Number'}]
            }
        , tel: {type: String, required: true, 'default':''}
        , address: { data: Buffer, contentType: String,default:''  }        
        ,price : { type: 'Number',default:''}
        ,disPrice: {type: 'Number',default:''}
        ,count: {type: 'Number',default:''}
        ,expireTime : {type: Date, index: {unique: false} }

});
```